# Partial incorrectly rendered with ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable, rails-activejob

I have a basic chat app which sends the messages via ActionCable. I am trying to sort the messages to the left/right depending on who has sent it, pretty much like Facebook's messenger app. 
I am trying to achieve it with a basic logic in the partial (_message.html.erb) that I send:

```
<%if message.user_id == current_user.id %> 
//message is to the right with inline CSS
<% else°%>
// message is to the left with inline CSS
<% end°%>
```

It works just fine if someone reloads the page but when the app is used all the new messages sent via ActionCable are send to the right.

I checked the partial which is sent and it seems that the

```
<%if message.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

runs on the users' side and then always the first part of the partial is being sent but not the whole _message.html.erb. Is there a way to instead send the whole partial and make sure that the

```
<%if message.user_id == current_user.id %>
```

runs when the message is received by all the subscribed users?

Messages controller:

```
if @message.save
  RoomChannel.broadcast_to @room.id, message: 
  MessagesController.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: 
  @message, current_user: current_user})
```

room.js:

```
received: function (data) {
    $('.messages').append(data.message);
}
```

If any further parts of the code is needed pls ask or: https://github.com/TTARJAN/chatApp

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up making two partials and broadcast them both with Actioncable and then let JQuery decide in the received function which one to render. Also, every users' ID is stored as a data in html to compare. Code below:

```
 var userId = $('#noBGR').attr('data-user-id');
    if (parseInt(userId) === data.id){
        $('.messages').append(data.msg_user);
    }else{
        $('.messages').append(data.message);
    }


RoomChannel.broadcast_to @room.id, id: @message.user_id, message: 
MessagesController.render(partial: 'messages/message', locals: {message: @message, 
current_user: current_user}), msg_user: MessagesController.render(partial: 
'messages/message_user', locals: {message: @message, current_user: current_user})
```